# If $f\leq\max(g_1,g_2)$ with $g_1,g_2$ convex functions and $f$ a concave function, does there exist $0\leq t\leq 1$ such that $f\leq t g_1+(1-t)g_2$?

Tags: probability, convex-analysis

Consider the following statement:

Let $X$ be real vector space (or more generally a convex space, a.k.a.
a barycentric algebra) and let $f,g_1,g_2 : X \to \mathbb {R}$ be three
functions such that $f$ is concave and $g_1, g_2$ are convex. If $f(x)
\leq \max(g_1(x), g_2(x))$ for all $x \in X$, then there exists  $t
\in [0,1]$ such that $f(x) \leq t g_1(x) + (1-t) g_2(x)$ for all $x$.

My questions are:

- First things first: is this statement true? I think I see how to prove it, but maybe I made a mistake somewhere (in which case, apologies for wasting your time). I tried to look for references and couldn't find anything, which I think bodes ill. On the other hand, I didn't really know where to look.
- If so, can you point to any references?
- In addition, do you know of any relevant theoretical tools that might provide a more conceptual proof and that I should have in mind when attempting to state and prove generalisations of this statement (if it is indeed true)? Maybe something from the toolbox of convex optimisation?

A bit of context, just in case: I'm interested in generalisations of this statement with more than two functions $g_i$ on the right-hand side. This is why I stated it in terms of convex and concave functions rather than linear functions as I originally intended: if I'm not mistaken, this version can be extended by induction to finitely many $g_i$s, and I think it can be stretched to countably many. Beyond that, I'm thinking of the case where the set $I$ of indices is a standard Borel space, $X$ is an algebra for the Giry monad on standard Borel spaces, and the functions $f,(g_i)_{i\in I}$ are all morphisms of algebras for this monad (with $g_i(x)$ measurable wrt the pair $(i,x)$). And maybe we have to throw in the existence of a measurable selector for the maximising $i$. I have no idea how to tackle this version, though, or even if there is any chance for some version of it to be true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some ideas that could help. I assume that $f$ is linear and consider convex functions $g_i$, $i \in I$ for some index set $I$.

Now, lets suppose that
$$
f(x) \le g(x) := \sup\{ g_i(x) \mid i \in I\}
$$
and we further require
$$
f(x_0) = g(x_0)
$$
for some point $x_0$.
This yields that $f \in \partial g(x_0)$.
Now, there are various regularity results which gives you a representation of $\partial g(x_0)$ in terms of $\partial g_i(x_0)$, $i \in I(x_0) := \{j \in I \mid g_j(x_0) = g(x_0)\}$. Typically,
you get that (under some assumptions)
$\partial g(x_0)$ is the closed convex hull of $\bigcup_{i \in I(x_0)} \partial g_i(x_0)$.

In your case,  this should give you the desired $t$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, what do you mean by $\partial g$? And what regularity results do you have in mind? (Or in which books should I look, if you don't have any precise result in mind)

Comment: $\partial g$ is the convex subdifferential of $g$. You can have a look in books concerning convex analysis/convex geometry. One result that I am aware of is Theorem 2 in Section 4.2 of the (old) book "Theory of Extremal Problems" by Ioffe and Tikhomirov.

Comment: I realized that your problem statement is quite general. For my post, $X$ has to be a normed space (or at least a locally convex topological Hausdorff space). One might also need some (semi)continuity of the involved functions.

Comment: I think your answer plus theorem 3 of the section you mentioned (which states that the $\overline{\operatorname{conv}}(\bigcup_{i\in I(x_0)}\partial g_i(x_0)) = \partial g(x_0)$ if $g_i(x_0)$ is continuous wrt $i$) do answer my question when $I$ is finite (or a compact topological space). Thank you for the pointer, I accepted your answer!

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think I'll find an answer there for the generalised problem, were $I$ is a standard Borel space and I only have measurability wrt $i$, not continuity. This is not too surprising because any such result would surely involve the condition that $f,g_i$ are morphisms of algebras over the Giry monad, which is a stronger condition than linearity (even than linearity+continuity), and I don't think many books look at this condition at all. Thank you anyway!